# Get only time from Date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

How to get only time from the date with am/pm. Below is my code what I have tried so far:

```
func changeFormat(str:String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let newDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    // step 1
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm aa" // input format
    newDateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm aa" // output format
    
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)!

    // step 2
    
    let string = newDateFormatter.string(from: date)
    
    
    return string
}
```

Usage:

```
let strTimeFromDate = changeFormat(str: self.response?.Data[indexPath.row].ADateTime ?? "")
```

input date:

```
06/22/2021 2:00 PM
```

output:

```
12:45 PM
```

Getting wrong time return after formatting. Please guide what's wrong with above code

Comment: "HH" is for 24h format and "aa" is for 12h format so you can't mix them, try "hh:mm a" instead

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes thanks, that's the only reason. A very minor thing but very important. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Please post your answer, so that I can accept it and it will be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"HH" is for 24h format and "aa" is for 12h format so you can't mix them, so you should use "hh:mm a" instead for both DateTimeFormatter's

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by *@JoakimDanielson* in the comment, you are mixing `HH` (24 hours format) with `hh` (12 hours format). Using `hh` for the `dateFormatter` (given your input has `02:00 PM`) should fix your issue (**as long as this input value was captured in the same time zone in which you intend to convert**).

---

In case you are still seeing that the output is not expected, then it is the issue with missing `timeZone` info in your input. You are trying to convert `String > Date > String` without specifying an input timeZone & output timeZone. You can try printing these values in your implementation.

```
print("dateFormatter.timeZone.secondsFromGMT() : \(dateFormatter.timeZone.secondsFromGMT())")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)!
print("parsed date : \(date)")
print("\n ------------------------ \n")

// step 2
print("newDateFormatter.timeZone.secondsFromGMT() : \(newDateFormatter.timeZone.secondsFromGMT())")
let string = newDateFormatter.string(from: date)
print("parsed string : \(string)")
```

For me it prints following. `19800 / (60 * 60) = 5.5 (+05:30)`

```
dateFormatter.timeZone.secondsFromGMT() : 19800
parsed date : 2021-06-22 06:30:00 +0000

 ------------------------ 

newDateFormatter.timeZone.secondsFromGMT() : 19800
parsed string : 12:00 PM
```

The issue is - for these two conversions to happen correctly - you must specify an appropriate time zone.

1. `String` to `Date`
2. `Date` to `String`

Here's what that implementation could look like. Assuming input is `"06/22/2021 2:00 PM +0530"`

```
func changeFormat(str: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: Int(5.5*60*60)) // +05:30
    
    let newDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    newDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: Int(5.5*60*60)) // +05:30
        
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa Z"
    newDateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm aa"
        
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)!
    let string = newDateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return string
}
```

When you are consuming this date string from your backend server, you should consider using appropriate time zone for it. An example, assuming input is `"06/22/2021 2:00 PM +0000"` -

```
func changeFormat(str: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) // Server timeZone (UTC)
        
    let newDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    newDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current // User's timeZone
        
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa Z"
    newDateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm aa"
        
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)!
    let string = newDateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return string
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the time zone, can you give me any reason why the two instances of DateTimeFormatter in OP's code would use different time zones? Because if thew use the same zone then clearly the time zone can't be part of the problem, right?

Comment: OP has these values `input = 06/22/2021 2:00 PM` & `output = 12:45 PM`. One reason is `HH`(for 24 hours format) vs `hh`(for 12 hours format) as you already suggested in the comment. Other is `timeZone` given the input string is NOT aware of which timeZone it was capture in. I explained this why OP should capture `Z` part in input for it to convert correctly across time zones.

Comment: But the fact that there is no time zone given in the input string is an essential part of the question and then my change is all that is needed. With a time zone in the input string you have a very different question even if that is a much better input than OP has now.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes it is, I have edited the post to reflect this clearly. Thanks!